# MongoDb with Java foreign key

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need to save two collections in my MongoDB using Java. Where one collection is **Department** and other collection is **Employee**. Where one Department can have many employees I want to save a collection like an employee unique ID has to mapped in my department employee list.

Example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598da19250aa4ad2413d4bc0"),
    "_class" : "com.department",
    "departmentName" : "SAQ-A",
    "departmentNumber" : "3_2",
    "employee" : [ 
           "id" : "1",
           "id" : "2",
           "id" : "3"
     ]
}
```

Can I know what is the way I can achieve it in MongoDB using Java?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the provided document and tags I assume you are using spring data to deal with mongodb. So here you may want to use DBRefs to bind employees into departments. Luckily [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references) gives you @DBRef annotation.

Employee class:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    ...

}
```

Department class:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Department {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
    ...
}
```

MongoDB document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("598dc04ac4fdd0e29867ccbb"),
    "_class" : "foo.bar.Department",
    "employees" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "employee",
            "$id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "employee",
            "$id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** Employee instance must already exist in MongoDB. DBRef will not save Employees in cascade style. Look at this article about [cascading](http://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb).

Answer (score 0):

If $id didn't work try just id like this

"employees" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "employee",
            "id" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "employee",
            "id" : 2
        }
    ]