# Using ObjectId as String in Java (Manual reference) with spring-data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

In MongoDB documentation they suggest to use ObjecId for manual references.
please see  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references

```
original_id = ObjectId()

db.places.insert({
    "_id": original_id,
    "name": "Broadway Center",
    "url": "bc.example.net"
})

db.people.insert({
    "name": "Erin",
    "places_id": original_id,
    "url":  "bc.example.net/Erin"
})
```

I'm using **spring-data-mongodb** and what I'm looking for is to have a *People* class defined like this:

```
@Document
public class People {

    private String name;
    @Reference // or any Annotation to convert an ObjectId to a String
    private String placesId; 
    private String url;
}
```

How to have a "places_id" as ObjectId in mongoDB but mapped to a String in our POJO ?

I was expecting to have an annotation like **@Reference** but it seems to not be implemented.

I don't understand why we don't have this kind of annotation in spring-data-mongodb. I don't want to implement an explicit converter like suggested in [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-explicit-converters) for all documents that use manual references.
Maybe it's not the right approach.

Did I miss something ?

**UPDATE :**

I like the idea to have a POJO using only String instead of ObjectId.  Let's say I've got a class **Place** like this :

```
@Document
public class Place {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

`place.getId()` will be a String but `people.getPlaceId()` will be an ObjectId.  I want to avoid this unnecessary mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you leave the field as ObjectId?

```
@Document
public class People {

    private String name;
    private ObjectId placesId; 
    private String url;
}
```

If you want to query by this field you can do this:

- For lists

  ```
  List<String> ids // the ids as strings
  List<ObjectId> objIds = ids .stream()
                              .map(i -> new ObjectId(i))
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- For single String

  ```
  String id // single id
  ObjectId objId = new ObjectId(id);
  ```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I've updated my question with more details because I would like to avoid this mapping.  But what you're suggesting is working.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no specific annotation provided yet. Only field [`_id` is handled in the mapping layer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.id-handling). _When using the MappingMongoConverter there are certain rules that govern how properties from the Java class is mapped to this _id field_

Comment: But you could look into customizing the `MappingMongoConverter`

Answer (score 8):

The solution would be:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType;

public class People {

    @Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String placesId; 
}
```

This will map POJO string to ObjectId in MongoDB.

Comment: What can be done if there is `List<String>` instead of `String`? I mean list of object Ids.

Comment: Good question. I would probably raise a ticket for [Spring Data MongoDB GitHub project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb), because somebody would ask for `Set` instead of `List` and so on.

Comment: @dma_k Any solution for List<String> ? I mean it's only 3 months but still gotta ask.

Comment: I don't have any solution, you'd better ask Spring Data community. Probably one can hack by implementing a custom converter?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a real reference to an other object in your database, use the `@DBRef` annotation which is provided by `Spring Data`.

Your updated code could look like the following:

```
@Document
public class People {

    private String name;

    @DBRef
    private Place place; 
    private String url;
}
```

Spring Data will then automatically map a `Place` object to your `People` object. Internally this is done with a reference to the unique `ObjectId`. Try this code and have a look at your mongo database.

For more information have a look at: [MongoDb with java foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636064/mongodb-with-java-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution very simple:

```
@JsonSerialize(using= ToStringSerializer.class)
private ObjectId brandId;
...
```

put that on the attribute that is Object Id, and the ObjectId gets and inserts like string